# How to pass non-form data in django form object?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a data dictionary and want to validate and clean that data to store in database table as defined in models.py

My approach was creating a form class then create an instance of that form class and pass data dictionary instead of request.POST in the view.py.

But this is not working. No error, but  cleaned_data returning an empty dictionary.

```
    data = {
        'story_title': i.title.text,
        'story_source': Sources.objects.get(source_url= source_url),
        'pub_date': i.pubDate.text[5:16],
        'body_text': des,
        'url': i.link.text

        }
    story_form = StoryForm(data)
    if story_form.is_valid():
        story_data = story_form.cleaned_data
        new_story = Stories(
            story_title = story_data['story_title'],
            story_source = story_data['story_source'],
            pub_date = story_data['pub_date'],
            body_text = story_data['body_text'],
            url = story_data['url']

        )
        new_story.save()
```

I am not confirm that my approach is right or wrong. 
While searching for solution I came across  HttpRequest.body in Django docs which only says that HttpRequest.body is used to populate form instance with the non-form data / raw data (nothing about how to use).

Comment: Your approach should work - it's probably just that your data is failing to validate. Inspect `form.errors` after calling `is_valid()` to see why validation failed. If you use a `ModelForm` then you won't have to manually repopulate the data into your `Stories` model either.

Comment: @solarissmoke actually I have tried to print the story_data in if condition after story_data = story_form.cleaned_data , which is printing an empty dictionary, Since flow is going  in if condition, which clears that story_form is valid.

Comment: In that case the issue must be with the form - how have you defined `StoryForm`?